# Primitive type decimal in Java - User Entry

Tags: java

I am doing an exercise in which the user has to input a signed four digit decimal number such as `+3364`, `-1293`, `+0007`, etc using Java programming language.

As far as I know, Java does not support a primitive type decimal.
My questions are:

1. How can I enter numbers like above?
2. How can I provide a +, - sign for the above numbers?

UPDATE

The code below shows a snippet in which it asks the user to enter a valid number (no characters) - the unary + is not working using the code below!! is there a way to fix it.

```
public int readInt() {
    boolean continueLoop = true;
    int number = 0;
    do {
        try {
            number = input.nextInt();
            continueLoop = false;
        } // end try
        catch (InputMismatchException inputMismatchException) {
            input.nextLine();
            /** discard input so user can try again */
            System.out.printf("Invalid Entry ?: ");
        } // end of catch
    } while (continueLoop); // end of do...while loop

    return number;
} // end of method readInt()
```

Comment: See my answer. You can do it with regular expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java has 8 primitive (non-Object/non-Reference) types:

- `boolean`
- `char`
- `byte`
- `short`
- `int`
- `long`
- `float`
- `double`

If, by "decimal" you mean "base 10 signed integer", then yes, Java supports that via `byte`, `short`, `int` and `long`.  Which one you use will depend on the input ranges, but `int` is the most common, from what I've seen.

If, by "decimal" you mean "base 10 signed floating-point number with absolute precision" similar to C#'s `Decimal` type, then no, Java does not have that.

If `Scanner.nextInt` is throwing an error for you, like it is me, then the following should work:

```
/* Create a scanner for the system in. */
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
/*
 * Create a regex that looks for numbers formatted like:
 * 
 * A an optional '+' sign followed by 1 or more digits; OR A '-'
 * followed by 1 or mored digits.
 * 
 * If you want to make the '+' sign mandatory, remove the question mark.
 */
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\+?(\\d+))|(\\-\\d+)");

/* Get the next token from the input. */
String input = scan.next();
/* Match the input against the regular expression. */
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(input);
/* Does it match the regular expression? */
if (matcher.matches()) {
    /* Declare an integer. */
int i = -1;
/*
 * A regular expression group is defined as follows:
 * 
 * 0 : references the entire regular expression. n, n != 0 :
 * references the specified group, identified by the nth left
 * parenthesis to its matching right parenthesis. In this case there
 * are 3 left parenthesis, so there are 3 more groups besides the 0
 * group:
 * 
 * 1: "(\\+?(\\d+))"; 2: "(\\d+)"; 3: "(\\-\\d+)"
 * 
 * What this next code does is check to see if the positive integer
 * matching capturing group didn't match. If it didn't, then we know
 * that the input matched number 3, which refers to the negative
 * sign, so we parse that group, accordingly.
 */
if (matcher.group(2) == null) {
    i = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));
} else {
    /*
     * Otherwise, the positive group matched, and so we parse the
     * second group, which refers to the postive integer, less its
     * '+' sign.
     */
        i = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
    }
    System.out.println(i);
} else {
    /* Error handling code here. */
}
```

Alternatively, you can do it like this:

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = scan.next();
    if (input.charAt(0) == '+') {
        input = input.substring(1);
    }
    int i = Integer.parseInt(input);
    System.out.println(i);
```

Basically just remove the '+' sign if there's one and then parse it.  If you're going to be doing programming, learning regular expressions is very useful, which is why I gave you that, instead.  But if this is homework and you're worried that the teacher will get suspicious if you use something that is beyond the scope of the course, then by all means do not use the regular expression approach.

Comment: Thank you Jared for the post - but I simply do not understand the Pattern in your code snippet above - I do not have this programming skills to use this code - if possible can you explain your code please!

Comment: I recently added a (ton) of comments.  Do they not explain it well enough for you?

Comment: Thank you Jared, I have not seen before in your code snippet!!

Comment: You're welcome!  And I added another approach, too, if you prefer :)

Comment: @Jared, it is not a homework !! I am basically learning Java at my own currently and simply if I get stuck in something I ask and hope to get results!! I must thank you for your posts and the time spent in getting around this problem.

Comment: I think BigDecimal(Java7) is the equivalent for .net decimal. Can you confirm?

Answer (score 3):

Use [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter 3 integer numbers: ");
int a = scan.nextInt();
int b = scan.nextInt();
int c = scan.nextInt();
System.out.print("You have entered: " + a + " | " + b + " | " + c);
```

**OUTPUT:**

> Enter 3 integer numbers: +3364 -1293 +0007
>   You have entered: 3364 | -1293 | 7

---

**A side note:** Be careful when you are using leading 0's with integer numbers like `0007`, because it's interpreted in Java as octal number not decimal number. So, `010` is actually `8` in decimal base system, not `10`.

```
System.out.print(010);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
8
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Note that `Scanner` requires the signs `+` and `-` to be sticked to the number like `+5432` and `-5432`, not as `+ 5432` nor `- 5432`.

Comment: Note that you can not use ``Integer.parseInt()`` because it does not accept unary ``+``. ``Scanner`` is OK for this.

Comment: +123
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "+123"
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2097)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2050)
 at Main.main(Main.java:6)

Comment: Thank you Fouad for your answer - but as Jared said I am getting an inputMismatchException every time I tried to put + infront of the number. I am not sure how to solve this problem!!

Comment: This seems very strange as [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) documentation tells that it should parse unary + well. Syntax:  ``Integer  :: = ( [-+]? ( Numeral ) )``

Comment: @Alexey - I tried to put the + sign infront of the number and the compiler issues an exception (InputMismatchException).

Comment: @Fouad, can you please check the code snippet in Mokoto post below. I highly appreciate your reply. thank you.

Comment: @Sinan Append it to your question.

Comment: @Sinan I tried your code, and it's working without any problem. Make the declaration of `input` Scanner within your method, I suspect you used it in another method, and it still holds a new-line character `\n` in it. One last advice, make your method as a static method since it does not contain any instance fields.

Comment: @Fouad, you are right, the Scanner method is already defined the code as a Static instance variable!! sorry for not posting it in the code snippet above.
private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class to read the values.  You will have to do a bit more work to ensure that + is not part of your conversion to Integer (check the [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) wrapper class), as `Scanner` won't accept + as a unary operator (it works fine with negative).

Comment: Thank you for your answer - my main problem is with the + sign and i have no idea how to get over it and let the Scanner read it!! also the other problem I have is the leading zeros infront of the number !!

Comment: Actually, `Scanner` accepts `+` as well as `-`, see my answer.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad:  I just tried it again (Java 6, mind you), and it still spits out an exception.

Comment: @Eng Fouad, I am trying to insert the + using the code below - the snippet shows an example of readInt() method which I wrote to accept only integers from user and if the user tries to enter invalid character then it keeps asking the user until it gets a valid number,

Comment: public int readInt()
 {
  boolean continueLoop = true;
  int number = 0;
  do 
  {
   try
   {
    number = input.nextInt();
    continueLoop = false;
   }// end try

   catch (InputMismatchException inputMismatchException) 
   {
    input.nextLine();
    /** discard input so user can try again */
    System.out.printf("Invalid Entry ?: ");
   }// end of catch

  } while (continueLoop); // end of do...while loop

  return number;
 }// end of method readInt()

Comment: @Makoto I tried it on Java 7, Java 6, and even Java 3, and it's working well. See the last update of my answer.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad:  It *still* breaks, even with your test data.

Comment: @Makoto Then what's the problem? :\

Comment: oops, I meant Java 5 not Java 3

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at fixed point numbers. The [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class can format this for you.