# Print String ArrayList in decimal and binary format

Tags: java, string, arraylist, binary, decimal

I have an ArrayList that I want to print in decimal and binary format.

Current output: decimal: S:2 S:3 S:3 S:3 S:1 S:2

Expected:

decimal:   2   3   3   3   1   2 
binary :  10  11  11  11   1  10

Any help is appreciated on how I can accomplish this.

I get this error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method toBinaryString(int) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (List)at generics.ExampleGenerics.main(ExampleGenerics.java:50)"

I am learning generics, do I need to cast an int to the string array to get this to work? or am I way off?

```
public class ExampleGenerics {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List < Square > squareList = new ArrayList < > (Arrays.asList(new Square(1),
            new Square(2), new Square(2), new Square(3), new Square(3), new Square(3)));
        System.out.println("original squareList: " + squareList);

        Collections.rotate(squareList, -2);
        System.out.println("rotated list: " + squareList);
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(squareList)); //error 
    }
}

public class Square {
    private int side;

    public Square(int side) {
        this.side = side;
    }

    public int getSide() {
        return side;
    }

    public void setSide(int side) {
        this.side = side;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "S:" + side;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + side;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof Square))
            return false;
        Square other = (Square) obj;
        if (side != other.side)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're attempting to pass your `List` to the method `Integer.toBinaryString()`. However, this method doesn't take Lists, it takes ints. This is stated in the exception: "The method toBinaryString(int) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (List)".

Instead of passing in your `List`, you need to loop through it and pass in the `int` for each `Square` object. So instead of doing this:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(squareList));
```

Do this:

```
for(Square square:squareList){
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(square.getSide()));
}
```

Comment: thank you! I was thinking I needed a for each loop. One last question, Looking at the Java Integer API there is a toBinaryString, toHexString method etc. However, I don't see a way to convert to decimal. What would you suggest, can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean by decimal? Are you referring to fractions? for instance 1.23? If that's what you're going for, you don't want to use `int`, you want `double`. Reading up on the [primitive data types in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) might prove useful. You might also want to read [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10064845/8972283). Further, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13252940/8972283) details how to convert an `int` to a `double`.

Comment: Thank you once again, I found what I was looking for with those links :)